# Visual Basic .NET limit a process to a single thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2013

How do you keep a Visual Basic program (or, better, only a single portion of it) to a single thread? For example

```
[Hypothetical thread limiting command here]
     my code and such
[End thread limitation]
```

Is there any way to do this? Sorry if I am being ambiguous.

Comment: My question, **why**?

Comment: Are you looking for `SyncLock`?

Comment: @436f6465786572 For a project I am working on. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm not sure, I'll fiddle with it and see if I can get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are explicitly starting other threads, or are using a 3rd party library that uses threads, Visual Basic (or any other .NET language) will not run with multiple threads.  You may see some debugging messages about threads starting and shutting down, but those are from the garbage collector running in the background and not your application.

Web projects are an exception to this, as each request will be handled on a separate thread.

### **UPDATE**

What you are seeing is most likely a combination of multiple effects.

The most important being something called [Hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).  Despite it's name, it has nothing to do with threads at the application level.  Most likely the CPU in your computer has only 2 physical cores that support Hyper-threading (HT).  HT will make each physical core show up as 2 logical cores in the operating system.  The CPU will decide to process instructions on one or both of these cores on its own.  This isn't true multi-threading, and you will never have to worry about any effects from HT in your code.

Another cause for what you are seeing is called [Processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity)(PA), or more properly, the lack of PA.  The operating system has the choice of which logical CPUs to execute your code on.  It also has the option of moving that execution around to different CPUs to try and optimize its workload. It can do this whenever it wants and as often as it wants; sometimes it can happen very rapidly.  Depending on your OS you can "pin" a program to a specific core (or set of cores) to stop this from happening, but again, it won't should not affect your program's execution in any way.

As far as the rise in CPU temperature you are seeing across all core, it can be explained pretty easily.  The physical cores on your CPU are very close together, under a heat-sink.  As one core heats up it will warm up the other core near it.

Comment: So as a test, I wrote a program that will iterate a simple equation through a bunch of times. I kept track of my CPU core usage while doing so. All 4 of my cores jumped both in usage and temperatures, from around 5% to 50% and 35C to 50C, respectively. Is this one thread somehow utilizing all 4 cores? What is going on in this instance?

Comment: Can you post your test code just so I can make sure I'm giving you an accurate explanation? I'll explain in more detail once I get to my PC.